# Sweetalert2 imageUrl isn't showing

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

My problem is that I tried both iconHtml and imageUrl and none of them is working for my unless I am using an url. However, in the documentation it says "Should contain a string with the path or URL to the image.". May be I'm doing something wrong? I tried full path, relative path, I tried importing and setting imported item for the path but nothing works unless I use an url. Any ideas from anybody who has been using swal2?

```
Store.swal.fire({
                titleText: 'some text',
                imageUrl: './icon.svg',
                imageWidth: 64,
                imageHeight: 64,
                confirmButtonText: 'Ок',
                customClass: {
                    confirmButton: 'swal-confirm-btn'
                }
            });}
```

Comment: `unless I am using an url` what's the other option are you trying except a URL?

Comment: I need to use path. Like in an example

Comment: Working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mendel-iqywj?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

U can try this one, give full path of the image where you have stored, in my case **assets/images/imagename.png** or any other format.

```
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'success',
          title: 'God Job...!!',
          text: 'successfully created!',
          imageUrl: '/assets/images/tick-circle.svg',
        })
```